# How to convert a for-loop to find the first occurrence to Java streams?

Tags: java, java-stream

I have the following code that is functionally working

```
for (UniversityClass class : allClasses)
    {
        Period<Date> classDate = class.getClassDates();
        if (classDate.start().before(classEndDate)
                && classDate.end().after(classBeginDate))
        {
            classBooked = true;
            break;
        }
    }
```

I have tried this:

```
allClasses.stream().filter(class -> {
            Period<Date> classDate = class.getClassDates();
            if (classDate.start().before(classEndDate)
                && classDate.end().after(classBeginDate))

            return true;
        }).findFirst().ifPresent($ -> {
            classBooked = true;
        });
```

But this throws to add a return statement. Also, the `classBooked` variable needs to be declared final, but that cannot be done. 
What is the mistake being done?

Also, once true, I need to `break` from it. that is why I thought of adding findFirst().ifPresent()

Comment: What does the filter function return if the `if` condition evaluates to false?

Comment: Lambda body is a kind of method. Specifically, `Predicate` (the one used in `filter()`) must return a `boolean`, and your implementation only returns `true` and never returns `false`. You should fix that. As for last point, lambdas are indeed not allowed to assign to variables defined outside. Note though, that `Optional` has `isPresent()` on, which works perfectly fine.

Comment: Also, both code samples don't compile, because `class` is a reserved keyword.

Answer (score 8, accepted):

You can use `anyMatch` in place of `filter`, `findFirst`:

```
classBooked = allClasses.stream()
                        .anyMatch(c -> {
                            Period<Date> classDate = c.getClassDates();
                            return (classDate.start().before(classEndDate) && classDate.end().after(classBeginDate));
                        });
```

You may also use `map` to be slightly more readable:

```
classBooked = allClasses.stream()
                        .map(UniversityClass::getClassDates)
                        .anyMatch(d -> d.start().before(classEndDate) && d.end().after(classBeginDate));
```

Comment: Not to need define temporary variable.`Period<Date> classDate = c.getClassDates();`

Comment: @HadiJ it's not needed, but since it's used twice it's more compact.

Comment: @HadiJ sure but the boolean expression will be slightly more long...

Comment: @HadiJ it is better to get the class dates only once since in my experiance the javac does not optimize multiple calls to getters and the getter could do what ever. So imho it is worth to introduce the variable to reduce the call count and also make it more readable.

Comment: @Ackdari this is why I defined the second form of stream!

Answer (score 8):

To fix the specific problems in your code, your lambda *always* needs to return a value, and the `ifPresent` needs to be changed to `isPresent`:

```
final boolean classBooked = allClasses.stream()
        .filter(c -> {
            final Period<Date> classDate = c.getClassDates();
            return classDate.start().before(classEndDate)
                && classDate.end().after(classBeginDate)
        })
        .findFirst().isPresent();
```

**However**, `anyMatch`, as shown in the other answers, is a better solution.

Answer (score 6):

you can do:

```
allClasses.stream()
          .anyMatch(uc-> (uc.getClassDates().start().before(classEndDate)
                              && uc.getClassDates().end().after(classBeginDate)));
```